# Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Prove $G \times \{1\}\unlhd G\times H$ and $(G\times H)/(G \times \{1\})\cong H$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ and $H$ be groups.
>
> - Prove that $G \times \{1\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times H$.
> - Prove that $(G\times H)/(G \times \{1\})$ is isomorphic to $H$.

My attempt below:

Let $(g_1,1)\in  G\times \{1\}$ and $(g_2,1)\in G\times \{1\}$ for some $g_1,g_2\in G$. Since $G$ is a group, it follows from closure that $g_1g_2\in G$. Therefore, $(g_1g_2,1)\in G\times \{1\}$. 
     From the group axioms, $g^{-1}\in G$, which means that $(g^{-1},1)\in G\times \{1\}$, so every element in $G\times \{1\}$ has an inverse.
     Additionally, $(g^{-1},1)(g,1)=(1,1)\in G\times\{1\}$, so $G\times\{1\}$ and $G\times H$ share the same identity element, which means that $G\times \{1\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times H$. Next, we want to show that $G\times \{1\}$ is normal to $G\times H$. To do this, we must show that $(g',1)(g,h)((g',1))^{-1}$ for some fixed $g'\in G$. So we have that $(g',1)(g,h)((g',1))^{-1}=(g,1)(g,h)(g'^{-1},1)=(g'gg'^{-1},h)$. Since $g'gg'^{-1}\in G$, we have that $(g'gg'^{-1},h)\in G\times H$. Therefore, $G\times \{1\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times H$.

I am confused about the last part of my proof, because I assumed some fixed g' and took $(g',1)(g,h)(g'^{-1},1)$ instead of $(g,h)(g',1)(g^{-1},h^{-1})$, although some of these ideas are still new to me, so I'm trying to figure out what mistakes to avoid. Also, I would like some pointers on some assumptions I made earlier that might have ruined the whole proof.

The next part of the proof is to prove that $(G\times H)/(G\times\{1\})$ is isomorphic to $H$. My approach for this one is to use the first isomorphism theorem. That is, to show that there is a map between these two groups that is a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: Yes for normality you should take $(g,h)(g',1)(g^{-1},h^{-1})$, but at the last coordinate this give you $1$, so no problem there. Hint for the last part: define $\phi : G \times H \rightarrow H$ by $\phi((g,h))=h$ and show that this a homorphism with kernel $ker(\phi)= G \times \{1\}$. By the way, this again proves $G \times \{1\}$ is normal!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know about group morphisms, you can avoid much work!

Consider the group morphism

$$\varphi: G \times H \to H: (g,h) \mapsto h$$

Clearly, this is a surjection with $\operatorname{ker}\varphi = G \times \{1_H\}$. Since the kernel of a group morphism is always a normal subgroup of the domain, we get $ G \times \{1_H\} \unlhd G \times H$ and by the first isomorphism theorem we get

$$(G \times H)/(G \times \{1_H\}) \cong H$$

as desired.